# Move files between folder on Amazon S3 using boto3 ( The specified bucket does not exist error)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to move file between a folder using boto3 , and using boto3 for this , example is here

```
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    # Copy object A as object B
    s3_resource.Object('dev-files', 'your-folder/my.txt').copy_from(
        CopySource='my-folder/my.txt')
    # Delete the former object A
    s3_resource.Object('dev-files', 'my-folder/my.txt').delete()
```

and getting this error :(

**An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the CopyObject operation: The specified bucket does not exist**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CopySource` parameter is defined as:

> The string form is {bucket}/{key} or {bucket}/{key}?versionId={versionId} if you want to copy a specific version. You can also provide this value as a dictionary. The dictionary format is recommended over the string format because it is more explicit. The dictionary format is: {'Bucket': 'bucket', 'Key': 'key', 'VersionId': 'id'}. Note that the VersionId key is optional and may be omitted.

Therefore this line:

```
CopySource='my-folder/my.txt')
```

should include the bucket name at the start:

```
CopySource='dev-files/my-folder/my.txt')
```